# Database of manufacturers of medical devices outside US

Tags: data-request, medical, europe, china

I'm doing some geospatial analysis of medical device manufacturers. In the US, the FDA requires manufacturers of medical devices to register their devices and the location of design and manufacturing.  This information is publicly posted in the “Establishment Registration & Device Listing” database, located at this address:

https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfRL/rl.cfm

This provides details such as the address of the location where a devices is manufactured. Are there comparable publicly available registration databases in the European Union or China?  Are there other (non-public) sources of this information?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for Europe is asking the [EMA - European Medicines Agency](http://www.ema.europa.eu/ema/), which is involved in regulating medical devices.

I am currently not aware of a public offering of the type of data you're requesting. Maybe someone can edit this answer.